# C# Windows Service - Getting Random Windows Error Reporting logs even when service not installed

Tags: c#, windows, service, error-handling, event-log

I'm currently working on a C# Windows Service.

I'm logging various things to the Windows Event Log, and using the Event Viewer to check the results.

As happens during development, things don't work, and every now and then Service would break and the Windows Error Reporting would log lots of entries like

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: MyServiceName.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5b9fcf54
P4: MyServiceName
P5: 1.0.0.0
P6: 5b9fcf54
P7: 280
P8: 16e
P9: System.NullReferenceException
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF8E3.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_MyServiceName_...

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 7c7efe65-6759-4a75-8581-72bc12182800
Report Status: 100
Hashed bucket: 
Cab Guid: 0
```

All fair enough, or so I thought.

The problem is that I'm getting these reports at random times as well.

It might log them after five minutes, or half an hour, or anywhere in between.

I started off thinking something was broken, and trying to find the bug, but then it logged a load of errors while the service was uninstalled. Not just not running, completely uninstalled.

I have now tried all of the following, and I am STILL getting these random Windows Error Reporting logs, which is making it impossible to tell actual problems from this random junk:-

1) Uninstall the Service

It's not showing up in the Services App list.

If I start a Command Prompt in Administrator mode and type:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc queryex MyServiceName
```

it returns

```
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060:
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

If I look through Processes and Services in Task Manager, nothing shows up

The service is uninstalled!

2) Rebooting

Just in case something was still in memory

3) Deleting every reference to MyServiceName in the Windows Registry

In case these was a dodgy registry key still kicking about

4) Rebooting

If all else fails...

5) Deleting the .EXE file

So there's no way it can be loaded and run

6) Rebooting yet again

Because why not!

And still, within a few minutes of rebooting, there they are...

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: MyServiceName.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5b9fcf54
P4: MyServiceName
P5: 1.0.0.0
P6: 5b9fcf54
P7: 280
P8: 16e
P9: System.NullReferenceException
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERF8E3.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_MyServiceName_...

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 7c7efe65-6759-4a75-8581-72bc12182800
Report Status: 100
Hashed bucket: 
Cab Guid: 0
```

And a couple of dozen others just like it.

I haven't installed or run the Service since I started trying to get rid of these random errors, and as I mentioned I've even deleted the .EXE files so it can't be installed or run.

Anyone know why I'm still getting this random junk, and more importantly how to stop it?

Edit: JuanR asked for the AppCrash file, so here it is:-

```
Version=1
EventType=CLR20r3
EventTime=131817392609639254
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131817585683279486
ReportStatus=100
ReportIdentifier=428e2b66-f3ae-461f-8221-df0633ba6dad
IntegratorReportIdentifier=e2ac36e7-3506-403f-9efc-cd22cfac94da
Wow64Host=34404
Wow64Guest=332
NsAppName=MyServiceName.exe
OriginalFilename=MyServiceName.exe
AppSessionGuid=000015b4-0000-0007-71e5-c234384fd401
TargetAppId=W:00064dae5f701edaa06ce44c0466d2ceb81300000000!0000a6504bbe6f18e0042ad1f80d12f5a7c97896d572!MyServiceName.exe
TargetAppVer=2018//09//18:10:11:10!0!MyServiceName.exe
BootId=4294967295
ServiceSplit=13
TargetAsId=2065
IsFatal=1
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01
Sig[0].Value=MyServiceName.exe
Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02
Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0
Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03
Sig[2].Value=5ba0cf3e
Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04
Sig[3].Value=System
Sig[4].Name=Problem Signature 05
Sig[4].Value=4.7.3151.0
Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06
Sig[5].Value=5b44403a
Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07
Sig[6].Value=2da3
Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08
Sig[7].Value=11f
Sig[8].Name=Problem Signature 09
Sig[8].Value=System.Security.Security
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.17134.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=2057
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=2beb
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=2beba6fb4680d73a8c78ca7c24ccdb46
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=b1f0
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=b1f0b380dbcd74b72a4df4e63607c2ae
UI[2]=C:\TFSOnline\Tools\MyServiceName\MyServiceName\bin\Debug\MyServiceName.exe
UI[5]=Check online for a solution (recommended)
UI[6]=Check for a solution later (recommended)
UI[7]=Close
UI[8]=MyServiceName stopped working and was closed
UI[9]=A problem caused the application to stop working correctly. Windows will notify you if a solution is available.
UI[10]=&Close
LoadedModule[0]=C:\TFSOnline\Tools\MyServiceName\MyServiceName\bin\Debug\MyServiceName.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\399032397425364b053c532bbbeacc09\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\6e52f5ddc8a0027c55a2c15df97d50a9\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\2d2bc5d43039ac23595b27676dcfcd3b\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\ce7b3ccf1b67903e135f62bd847db8dc\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\FLTLIB.DLL
LoadedModule[39]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\536177f34c4c0eeb95bcccd76ca90847\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iphlpapi.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[48]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[49]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[50]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\activeds.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\adsldpc.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\adsldp.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wkscli.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\logoncli.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DSPARSE.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msv1_0.DLL
LoadedModule[65]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NtlmShared.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptdll.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\psapi.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rasapi32.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rasman.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\rtutils.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\winhttp.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\secur32.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\schannel.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mskeyprotect.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\ncryptsslp.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml.Linq\6e4d9ba028653154945437d7674d20a3\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\WINDOWS\system32\security.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runteb92aa12#\5470ed48a2649b4c1fd9e883daa502b9\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
OsInfo[0].Key=vermaj
OsInfo[0].Value=10
OsInfo[1].Key=vermin
OsInfo[1].Value=0
OsInfo[2].Key=verbld
OsInfo[2].Value=17134
OsInfo[3].Key=ubr
OsInfo[3].Value=286
OsInfo[4].Key=versp
OsInfo[4].Value=0
OsInfo[5].Key=arch
OsInfo[5].Value=9
OsInfo[6].Key=lcid
OsInfo[6].Value=2057
OsInfo[7].Key=geoid
OsInfo[7].Value=242
OsInfo[8].Key=sku
OsInfo[8].Value=48
OsInfo[9].Key=domain
OsInfo[9].Value=1
OsInfo[10].Key=prodsuite
OsInfo[10].Value=256
OsInfo[11].Key=ntprodtype
OsInfo[11].Value=1
OsInfo[12].Key=platid
OsInfo[12].Value=10
OsInfo[13].Key=sr
OsInfo[13].Value=0
OsInfo[14].Key=tmsi
OsInfo[14].Value=48160
OsInfo[15].Key=osinsty
OsInfo[15].Value=3
OsInfo[16].Key=iever
OsInfo[16].Value=11.285.17134.0-11.0.85
OsInfo[17].Key=portos
OsInfo[17].Value=0
OsInfo[18].Key=ram
OsInfo[18].Value=8144
OsInfo[19].Key=svolsz
OsInfo[19].Value=445
OsInfo[20].Key=wimbt
OsInfo[20].Value=0
OsInfo[21].Key=blddt
OsInfo[21].Value=180410
OsInfo[22].Key=bldtm
OsInfo[22].Value=1804
OsInfo[23].Key=bldbrch
OsInfo[23].Value=rs4_release
OsInfo[24].Key=bldchk
OsInfo[24].Value=0
OsInfo[25].Key=wpvermaj
OsInfo[25].Value=0
OsInfo[26].Key=wpvermin
OsInfo[26].Value=0
OsInfo[27].Key=wpbuildmaj
OsInfo[27].Value=0
OsInfo[28].Key=wpbuildmin
OsInfo[28].Value=0
OsInfo[29].Key=osver
OsInfo[29].Value=10.0.17134.286.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804
OsInfo[30].Key=buildflightid
OsInfo[30].Value=39b802d6-2dc5-4161-973b-28cf09eb3ffb
OsInfo[31].Key=edition
OsInfo[31].Value=Professional
OsInfo[32].Key=ring
OsInfo[33].Key=expid
OsInfo[34].Key=containerid
OsInfo[35].Key=containertype
OsInfo[36].Key=edu
OsInfo[36].Value=0
File[0].CabName=WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[0].Path=WERCF72.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
File[0].Flags=327682
File[0].Type=5
File[0].Original.Path=\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERCF72.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=CLR20r3
AppName=MyServiceName
AppPath=C:\TFSOnline\Tools\MyServiceName\MyServiceName\bin\Debug\MyServiceName.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=9EE7A7FA2D9AD07D426D34AC6F6F0ACA
MetadataHash=1785215478
```

The path is mentions throughout is

```
C:\TFSOnline\Tools\MyServiceName\MyServiceName\bin\Debug\MyServiceName.exe
```

This is one of the EXEs I deleted. I also deleted the one in obj/Debug.

I've scanned the entire drive, using several methods, and no other instances of MyServiceName.exe exist, so it's not been copied anywhere.

And the one thing I realised I never mentioned: it's a Windows 10 machine

Edit #2:

None of the things the Service does, for example adding Windows Event logs, adding database table rows or creating files, are happening at the moment, so I'm reasonably sure the service isn't running.

I had all that working before starting to look into this issue, and haven't changed any of it since, so if it was running I'd expect to still see them.

To check, I've just re-installed the service as it was before, and I'm getting all the entries I expect.

Edit #3:

Tried deleting it with the SC command:-

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc delete MyServiceName.exe
[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

Comment: can you make the `AppCrash_MyServiceName...` file available?

Comment: My educated guess by the way is that the service is still running. You just don't know it's running.

Comment: You are not running application containers like Docker, are you?

Comment: Have you tried issuing the delete command with `sc` anyways? Also, make sure you are using an elevated command prompt: `sc delete MyServiceName`. Make sure to use the short name, not the display name.

Comment: Is it possibly that you previously installed it under a different name and didn't remove that registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

Nothing to do with the Service at all, just Windows being crap as always.

Turns out that every time Windows was logging a message, it was also churning out a load of old messages that had got stuck in its queue, and logging them as new messages.

I ran Disk Cleanup, and told it to clear out all the old error messages, and it's been running for three days now with no errors at all.

Comment: That sounds really stupid - in other words quite standard for Windows. Could you elaborate as to what evidence led you to discover this, so that other people facing the same problem can determine whether they have the same issue or not?